# Insert textbox value into python mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

How do I insert a Textbox value into Python mqsql database directly? I have tried it by writing the following statement into py(python) file:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Firstdb(First, Second) VALUES('" + self.t1.Text + "', '" + self.t2.text + "')")
```

But it is not working. Please help me to know the right syntax of storing textbox or any other control's value into python mysql database.

t1 is the id of textbox in kv file and I have assigned objectproperty(none) to t1 to access it in python (py) file. Please tell me if is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use parameter-passing style to prevent sql injection:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Firstdb(First, Second) VALUES(%s, %s)", [
    self.t1.text, self.t2.text
])
```

In addition to that, if the INSERT does not take effect, try to commit the change:

```
db_object.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

To be always sure, that what you're inserting is actually a string, convert it using str() function:

```
str(self.t1.Text)
```